# Creating S3 Bucket folders with different permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have a small web server for serving static files, which is setup to do the following:

- Accessing https://my.domain.com/dl/ gives a directory listing of all available files in /dl/.
- Accessing https://my.domain.com/dl/specific-file lets me download the specific resource in /dl/
- Accessing https://my.domain.com/dl2/ gives an error (currently it is a 403, but I'm not particular on what the error is
- Accessing https://my.domain.com/dl2/specfic-file lets me download the specific resource in /dl2/

So essentially, /dl/ is a repository of public files, and /dl2/ is a repository of private files. Translating this behavior to S3 does not seem to be straight forward however. Currently, my policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "StaticPolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DLALlowPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::static.spookyinternet.com/dl/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I'm unable to find any concrete documentation on how to set this up. How can I configure an S3 bucket to behave in this same way?

Edit: Some additional information, if it is applicable:
This will ultimately be sitting behind a cloudfront instance using my personal domain name.

Comment: Does resources in `dl2` are publicly accessible with direct S3 file link?

Comment: yes. If you have a direct link to a resource in /dl2/ you should be able to view/download it.

Comment: And when you go to `https://my.domain.com/dl2/specfic-file` that link does that somehow call the direct link?

Comment: https://my.domain.com/dl2/specific-file would be the direct link. specific-file is a place holder for some file found either in /dl/ or /dl2/. So for example, if I had a file named picture.jpg, https://my.domain.com/dl2/picture.jpg would be the direct link.

Comment: Ok, so that's the problem. Your files are first of all publicly accessible which cannot be prevented by any policy. Make the file is `dl2` private and your problems will go away

Comment: I don't understand? I want them to be publicly available. They just need the direct link to download them. I can set up that easily. Having /dl/ give a directory listing is where I am stuck

Comment: Ok, your post above give's the impression of that you've permission issue with `dl2`. The reason why `dl` allow directory listing could be due to marking the directory public? Have you marked the entire folder of `dl` as public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your desire is:

- A `dl` directory that can be listed, with all files accessible
- A `dl2` directory that **cannot** be listed, but all the files are accessible if somebody knows the name of the file

Firstly, this is a very poor security design. Just because somebody cannot list the `dl2` directory does not make your files secure. Anybody that knows a filename (or that can *guess* a filename) would have access to the files. [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not very good security.

Secondly, please note that permissions are not placed on **folders**. Rather, a Bucket Policy (such as the one you list) can grant permissions based upon a path, which is effectively the same as granting permissions on a folder-level.

Also, please note that Amazon S3 is not a traditional web server. It is an object storage system that also provides access to objects via HTTP/S calls. So, it can't do things like "give a directory listing of all available files in /dl/". (It can supply an XML listing of all files in a bucket, but you typically don't want to do that.)

Your desire to grant access to all files in `dl` can be satisfied by the Bucket Policy you show above. If you also wish to grant access to all files in `dl2` (which is bad from a security perspective), simply add that to the policy, eg:

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::static.spookyinternet.com/dl/*", 
             "arn:aws:s3:::static.spookyinternet.com/dl2/*"]
```

Your desire to list files in `dl` cannot be met by S3. You could choose to upload a default index.htm file and serve it through [static website sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)), but you would need an application to keep the list always up-to-date.

So, at a simple level, all your needs (except the ability to list `dl`) can be met with the Bucket Policy.

But what, you might ask, is a better way to do things? I'm glad you asked!

- Grant public access to `dl`
- Make a web page that lists the files and links to the files in `dl`
- When you want to provide *private files*, create an application where users have to authenticate. The application would verify their identity, determine whether they are allowed to access the files and then generate an [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that grants time-limited access to an object. Once the time expires, the URL no longer works. So, the files are kept private, but a special URL grants temporary access.